# How to Unit test an angular directive that has a bind('error', function(){})?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have an angular directive that replaces the image src of an element if the file does not exist and a 404 is returned. Here it is:

```
myApp.directive('fallBackSrc', function() {
    var fallBackSrc = {
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('error', function () {
                angular.element(this).attr("src", '/images/image-not-available.png');
            });
        }
    }
    return fallBackSrc;
}]);
```

This works as expected but now I am trying to unit test this directive, how will I trigger the 'error' that this function is bound to in jasmine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to test this you will need to spyOn the element.bind using [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html) and also use Jasmines 2.0 done function.

So in my example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nicholas_Murray/bsL8ro3s/) I have added a place holder image as a replacement image to stop it causing an error.

```
angular.module('components', [])
    .directive('fallBackSrc', function() {
        var fallBackSrc = {
            link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind('error', function () {
                    angular.element(this).attr("src", 'http://placehold.it/350x150');
                });
            }
        }
        return fallBackSrc;
    });
```

and in the test we can `spyOn` `element.bind` and return `error` when it is called

```
spyOn(element, 'bind').and.returnValue('error');
```

Also we need to use the done function for running specs that require testing asynchronous operations by passing it into the test to use in the `setTimeOut`.

```
describe('Directive: fallBackSrc', function() {
        describe('if the image does not exist it', function() {

        var element, scope;

        beforeEach(module('components'));

        beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
            element = angular.element('<img fall-back-src src="images/no-image.jpg" />');
            spyOn(element, 'bind').and.returnValue('error');
            scope = $rootScope;
            $compile(element)(scope);
            scope.$digest();
        }));

        it("should contain the place holder img src", function(done) {          
            setTimeout(function(){  
                console.log(element.attr('src'));
                expect(element.attr('src')).toEqual('http://placehold.it/350x150'); 
                done();
            }, 2000);
        });
    });

});
```